# 403 Forbiden error while sending SOAP request using Karate Framework

Tags: karate

I am using a SOAP XML payload to process a request using Karate. Below is the feature file created but changed the URL and the credentials

Feature:    The payload is accepted and a contract number is returned and values are mapped

Background:

```
* url 'https:xxxxxxx'
* configure readTimeout = 150000
* header Authorization = 'Basic' + {username: 'xxx', password: 'xxx'}
```

Scenario:(1) Submit the payload

```
# Send the request using the payload data
        
Given request read('../../../../../Data/GatewayBooking/DEV/TC20.xml')

And header Content-Type = 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'
When method post
```

Then status 200
And print "Response", response

Below is the error seen
13:07:57.043 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.043 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Server: awselb/2.0[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.043 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Date: Tue, 27 Apr 2021 03:07:57 GMT[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.043 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Type: text/html[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.043 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Content-Length: 118[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.044 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.044 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.044 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.044 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "403 Forbidden[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.044 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.044 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "

## 403 Forbidden

[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.044 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.044 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - http-outgoing-0 << "[\r][\n]"
13:07:57.047 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
13:07:57.048 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Server: awselb/2.0
13:07:57.048 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Date: Tue, 27 Apr 2021 03:07:57 GMT
13:07:57.048 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Type: text/html
13:07:57.048 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Content-Length: 118
13:07:57.048 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - http-outgoing-0 << Connection: keep-alive
13:07:57.053 [main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec - Connection can be kept alive indefinitely

Comment: definitely missing some header, take care of it or follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue